# text-field от utify не работает мигающий caret на iOs. Что делать?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

`text-field` от `utify` не работает курсор (`caret`)  на `iOs`. Что делать? Причем, если нажать кнопку "Домой" и зайти снова в браузер, курсор появляется. Как исправить эту ситуацию?

```
<v-text-field
    style="width: 25%; margin: 0 auto;"
    label="Ваше имя"   
    clearable
    :rules="[(str) => /^[А-ЯЁ'’ -]*$/i.test(str) || 'Поле заполнено не корректно!']">

</v-text-field>
```

Comment: Приведите минимально-воспроизводимый код

Comment: Привел в теле вопроса